# Java API or library to edit MS Office or Open Office files using UI

Tags: java, ms-office, openoffice.org

Is there a Java API or library available to edit MS office or open office files using user interface and that could be attached with a Java project?

I know about Apache POI for MS office or Java UNO API for Open Office files, but they are creating, changing file functionality by writing codes not using User Interface.

Comment: In other words, you want a version of MS Office in Java?

Comment: Not exactly. I need any library or api or plugin which can be integrated with java project to edit files visually.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a a free or commercially available office solution in Java that you could embed into your Swing application. The best bet might be to embed open openoffice.

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=32906) on how to do so. It's quite old, so it might not work exactly like described there, but in principle it should be possible.

Comment: Its an alternative but not an answer